# javascript if statement not working with ifValid when reading from a public array

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, arraylist

When ever I enter data into the newState only the first if statement executes.

And shows an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined". Im just trying to use plain javascript for my project.

I m guessing you edited the code but I cant see the changes because of the ranking system is preventing me from viewing the rest of the edits. How can I view them without being ranked high? @mikhail

```
var states = ["CA", "WA", "OR", "NV", "NM", "AZ", "WY", "MT"];
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
//Display valid states in textbox
var displayValidStates = function () {
    var statesString = " ";
    var i = 0;
    statesString += states[i] + " ";
    $("validStates").value = states;
}

var addState = function () {
    var newStateObj = $("newState").value;
    var isValid = true;
    if ($("newState").length != 2) {
        $("newState").value = "";
        $("newStateError").firstChild.nodeValue = "The state code must contain two letters.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (newStateObj == stateCodeLookup()) {
        $("newStateError").firstChild.nodeValue = "State code is already in list.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (isValid) {
        $("newState").value = "";
        $("newStateError").firstChild.nodeValue = " ";
        states[states.length] = $("newState").value.toUpperCase();
        isValid = true;
    }
}

var stateCodeLookup = function (stateCode) {
    stateCode = stateCode.toUpperCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        if (states[i] == stateCode) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var joinList = function () {
    var emailAddress1 = $("emailAddress1").value;
    var emailAddress2 = $("emailAddress2").value;
    var isValid = true;


if (emailAddress1 == "") {
    $("emailAddress1Error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This field is required.";
    isValid = false;
} else {
    $("emailAddress1Error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
}


if (emailAddress2 == "") {
    $("emailAddress2Error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This field is required.";
    isValid = false;
} else if (emailAddress1 !== emailAddress2) {
    $("emailAddress2Error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This entry must equal first entry.";
    isValid = false;
} else {
    $("emailAddress2Error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
}


if ($("firstName").value == "") {
    $("firstNameError").firstChild.nodeValue = "This field is required.";
    isValid = false;
} else {
    $("firstNameError").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
}


var stateCode = $("stateCode").value;
if (!stateCodeLookup(stateCode)) {
    $("stateCodeError").firstChild.nodeValue = "State code is invalid.";
    isValid = false;
} else {
        $("stateCodeError").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
    }


    if (isValid) {
        $("emailForm").submit();
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    displayValidStates();
    $("addNewState").onclick = addState;
    $("joinList").onclick = joinList;
    $("emailAddress1").focus();
}
```

:.
The html:

```
<label for="validStates">Valid states:</label>
<textarea id="validStates" cols="30" rows="2" disabled style="none"></textarea><br>
<label for="newState">State code to add:</label>
<input type="text" id="newState" size="1" maxlength="2" ><br>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="addNewState" value="Add State Code"><span id="newStateError"> </span><br><br>
```

Comment: Well i see quite a lot of misused `jQuery` there for a *plain javascript project*.

Comment: I suggest you put together a jsfiddle example showing what you mean

Answer (score 0):

If the DOM element you get with your (fake jQuery) function `$(...)` does not have a value, then `.value` returns `undefined`. Your code ignores the fact, that `.value` can be undefined several times and just calls another function on it, which raises an Exception.

You should check the return value of `.value` first and call additional functions only if it's the type you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` will return null if it can't find the target element.

Check to make sure you're looking for the right thing and while you're at it update your code to check for null before trying to do anything with the results:

```
var val = $("newState").value;
if (val !== null) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: if (newStateObj.length != 2 || newStateObj !== null) I did this to the if statement and it still says there is no value and prints out the first if error message.  @mikhail

Comment: If `newStateObj` is null you don't want to call `newStateObj.length`, your check should be `(newStateObj !== null && newStateObj.length !== 2)`

Comment: It reaches all the way to the second if statement but its not properly pulling the input from the html form so it says the .value is undefined.

Comment: You need to figure out why your object is not being found. Do you have an HTML object with the id "newState"? You're not showing your HTML.

Comment: Please put the HTML somewhere in your question rather than the comment. Thanks.

Comment: Added to the main post above.